# Is there an anti-control gate in Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I started play with the Qiskit, and can't find an anti-control not there. By "anti-control" I mean the gate is executed only for these states of the superposition, where control qubit is in the Zero state.
It's annoying to use a code like

```
circuit.x(control)
circuit.cx(control, target)
circuit.x(control)
```

I would rather prefer

```
circuit.acx(control, target)
```

On the circuits language, I want to use a control gate from

[image]

Is there a dedicated operation for it in the Qiskit?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own "anti-controlled" gate by specifying what to control an `x` gate on, using this method [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/3b3536bcdb83124d49723dd205573f169c82ea9c/qiskit/circuit/add_control.py#L24).

I think this would look something like

```
anti_gate = XGate.control(ctrl_state='0')
circuit.append(anti_gate, [control, target])
```

Comment: could you help with imports, please? "from qiskit.extensions.standard import XGate" handles XGate, but how to import control? "from qiskit.circuit import *" doesn't work

Comment: You shouldn't need to import control - the first mention of control is a method on the `XGate` and the second mention of control I was copying your terminology from the question, it is the qubit you want to control the gate on.

Comment: unfortunately, this functionality doesn't work properly at the moment, the fix is waiting for release: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4175 , https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4180 . In any case, you shown me the right direction, and I thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The other possible solution, if you using openQasm
Check that address
https://openqasm.com/language/gates.html#control-modifiers

There is example of usage

```
    // Define a negative controlled X operation using the negctrl gate modifier.
    // q1 is control, q2 is target
    gate neg_cx(θ) q1, q2 {
        negctrl @ x q1, q2;
    }
```